# Adding load balancer to Elastic Beanstalk leads 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My environment was up and running until I added a load balancer through the EB configuration console. Now I get a 502 bad gateway error. Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

I added the load balancer by going to EB console -> Configuration. Where I changed the Environment Type from Single Instance to Load Balanced.

My nginx error log is:

```
2021/08/09 02:07:30 [error] 3534#3534: *124 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.xx.xx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "myapplication-env.eba-2hp9xpc6.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

Comment: what is the status of health check of your target group and also have you tried this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/load-balancer-http-502-errors/

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that AWS could not find my projects manifest. I made a configuration change in `pom.xml` that broke the manifest and was the root of the issue.

More specifically, I had inadvertently wrapped my `maven-assembly-plugin` into the `<pluginManagement>` section of my `pom` without specifying the assembly plugin outside of `<pluginManagement>`.